# MySQL query returned an empyt result set

Tags: mysql

Im new to MySQL and I tried to create the following query:

```
SELECT locations.PuP, processing_system.deposited_timedate
FROM locations
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.fk_location = location_id
INNER JOIN processing_system ON processing_system.fk_emp = employee.emp_id
WHERE processing_system.deposited_timedate BETWEEN '2020-07-08 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-08 23:59:59'
```

[These are the tables I want to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwKg3.jpg)

[These are the data in the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv2WS.jpg)

The query seems to work unless it gives me just the table names without any data. Can somebody help to fix it?

Comment: Your JOINs or WHERE clause might be failing, First try querying without WHERE clause, even if you don't yield results then remove JOINs and try by adding one by one.

Comment: fix what? the absense of data?

Comment: I added the data of the tables in the second image. The problem is that I have the data in the tables but query returns an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are not receiving results as your fk_location in employee table is empty. So its a data issue in your table.
Can you try this. I have removed between and used comparison instead.

```
SELECT loc.Pup, psys.deposited_timedate
 FROM
    Locations AS loc
        INNER JOIN
    Employee AS emp ON emp.fk_location = loc.location_id
        INNER JOIN
    Processing_system AS psys ON psys.fk_emp = emp.emp_id
 WHERE
    psys.deposited_timedate > '2020-07-08 00:00:00'
        AND psys.deposited_timedate < '2020-07-08 23:59:59'
```

Comment: It still gives me an empty result. The PuP and deposited_timedate coloums are there but without any data.

Comment: Its not receiving data as the values in column fk_location is null, which are suppose to be from location table(location_id).
The join is failing because of that.

Comment: Its still empty, but you are right, I have data issues, so I think I have to fix it first then try again. Thanks!

Comment: Right, I find query is right, but because of invalid/null data you are not able to fetch results.

Thanks, hope you got an answer.